# How to perform "select top 1 x from table" statement in spark sql

Tags: sql-server, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I  am facing problem converting bellow query in spark-sql  in pyspark
SQL-server query is

```
coalesce((Select top 1 f2.ChargeAmt from Fact_CMCharges f2
        where f2.BldgID = f.BldgID 
        and f2.LeaseID = f.LeaseID
        and f2.IncomeCat = f.IncomeCat
        and f2.Period < f.Period
        and f2.ActualProjected = 'Lease'
        order by f2.Period desc),0) as Charge
```

I did not find replacing key word of top in pyspark sql . Kindly Help me 
how could i convert  this query in py-spark sql

Comment: I'm not familiar with sql-server. Would you care explaining what it does and a link reference for its documentation?

Comment: well 'top' works  like as limit keyword in MYSQL as i have understood. here this command actually  pick  top 1 row  from given condition in where clause.the coalesce statement will execute this statement if it is true or  return 0 by default

Comment: Can you give an example of an input data and expected output because it's still not very clear.

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_select_top&ss=-1  this link shows sql server 'top statement' example

Answer (score 1):

Since you said Spark-SQL and if you have `DF', then you can use something like this.

```
df.limit(1).show()
```

Comment: thanks for the reply . though i have not tried  data frame approach but i did  write limit 1 at end of the  sql query. and i have got this error message
pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: u'Correlated scalar subqueries must be Aggregated: GlobalLimit 1\n+- LocalLimit 1\n